# HOw to give dynamic array range in excel

Tags: excel

I need to refer to an array in an excel
The code would be

```
SUMIFS($P$4:$P$22159,$AE$4:$AE$22159,AZ4,$AE$4:$AE$22159,BA4)
```

The number of rows are 22159 as of now. But the number of rows changes in every iteration. How can I give a dynmic value to it.

Comment: SUMIFS(P4:P,$AE$4:$AE$22159,AZ4,$AE$4:$AE$22159,BA4)..I tried this but it does not work

Comment: Yes I did..It wont return a value as rows 1 to 4 are non numeric

Comment: Do `AZ4` and `BA4` contain numbers or text?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to make your ranges dynamic if the criteria are numeric:

```
=SUMIFS(P4:INDEX(P:P,MATCH(9E+99,P:P,1)),AE4:INDEX(AE:AE,MATCH(9E+99,AE:AE,1)),AZ4)
```

And here is a version if the criteria are instead text:

```
=SUMIFS(P4:INDEX(P:P,MATCH(9E+99,P:P,1)),AE4:INDEX(AE:AE,MATCH("*",AE:AE,-1)),AZ4)
```

Comment: @user2786962 Please let me know if this worked for you?